# change native function name from php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to create a function xxxx that will do the same as shell_exec. The reason is that I am disabling shell_exec in my server so nobody in it will be able to use it.

However for some users that need to use it, I will tell that they must not use shell_exec but another function named "xxxx". Doing so I can prevent lots of attacks to my server cause only my customers will know the alternative name of the function.

I know this users can give the function name to other people but that is not my concern at the moment.

I am asking this cause once I block function in disable_function at php.ini I cannot enable it again to specific websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without using some function like [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), proc_open, etc, which should all be disabled if you're trying to secure your server. If you're **only** disabling exec, you can just use [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/shell_exec) instead.